# Passing password with ssh in linux

Tags: ssh, scripting

I am trying to do the passwordless authentication for many number of servers from some of the main servers, so I wrote a script for that. But for copying keys to each the server I need to enter my password for the first time. But I am able to do this in the case of less servers but I want to do this for almost 1000 servers, so I am not ready to do this like entering the password for 1000 times.

The bad point in my case was I can't use sshpass command and expect utility for this where I don't have approval for this to install. So is there any other option to provide the password along with the ssh, also I will provide my script for automate the passwordless authentication.

### adding

I want to copy the keys to many servers from my master server without entering the password manually instead of providing the password with the ssh or in script. But I cannot use the sshpass or expect commands here.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo | ssh-keygen -P '' -t rsa

for i in `cat lists`
do
    cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh userid@$i "mkdir -p ~/.ssh;chmod 700 ~/.ssh;cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys;chmod 640 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
done
```

Comment: Take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279923/how-to-understand-ssh-keygen-and-ssh-copy-id - use ssh-copy-id

Comment: Hi steve, this is not given a slotion to me, I am clear about the passwordless authentication, my query is that "suppose I want to copy the ssh public key to many servers for the first time, I required to provide the password each time, so how can I avoid that by providing the password in the ssh command (without sshpass or expect)

Comment: `sshpass` worth a look, in that case.